# what is the difference between TCP_NODELAY and MSG_DONTWAIT

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

What is the difference between `TCP_NODELAY` and `MSG_DONWAIT`?I understand that one is specific to TCP and another is for generic socket option while sending, but does these two option behave differently in different scenarios?
  Just like `TCP_NODELAY`, is `MSG_DONTWAIT` also disables Nagle algorithm ?

To be specific, I am trying to send data over my local LAN network and I don't want my socket to be stuck because of any reason while sending,I just wish that it sends the packet and return immediately. which one is a better and more reliable option to do this.
(this question is specific to Linux sockets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TCP_NODELAY` won't help you here - the Nagle algorithm is just about how data is buffered in the TCP stack before it goes out, and won't affect control flow in your program. What you want is a non-blocking socket - send calls will return immediately and you can query them later to find out whether anything happened or not.

Comment: or use the socket in blocking mode, but move it to its own worker thread.

Comment: That would work, but that thread would still have to deal with the possibility of the socket getting stuck, and depending on what libraries you're using you're potentially looking at some quite complicated code to make the threading work properly.

Comment: Even in blocking mode, you can still use timeouts on reading and writing operations to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Blocking send only blocks if send buffer is full. If there is space in send buffer, both blocking and non blocking would take the same time.

Comment: Using a timeout to avoid a deadlock is better than having your app lock up forever, of course, but it's still non-optimal, because (a) your app will still be deadlocked and non-responsive until the next timeout occurs, and (b) regular timeouts mean your app will be waking up regularly even when there is no network traffic to process, which is inefficient -- particularly if your app is running on a portable device with a finite battery capacity.